# Custom type hint annotation

Tags: python, code-completion, type-hinting

I just wrote a simple [`@autowired` decorator](https://github.com/allrod5/injectable) for Python that instantiate classes based on type annotations.

To enable lazy initialization of the class, the package provides a `lazy(type_annotation: (Type, str))` function so that the caller can use it like this:

```
@autowired
def foo(bla, *, dep: lazy(MyClass)):
   ...
```

This works very well, under the hood this `lazy` function just returns a function that returns the actual type and that has a *lazy_init* property set to `True`. Also this does **not** break IDEs' (e.g., PyCharm) code completion feature.

### [But I want to enable the use of a subscriptable `Lazy` type use instead of the `lazy` function.](https://github.com/allrod5/injectable/issues/3)

Like this:

```
@autowired
def foo(bla, *, dep: Lazy[MyClass]):
   ...
```

This would behave very much like [typing.Union](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/7d7ffcd51e1ed9bccfa0466b371e490b1555208b/python2/typing.py#L773). And **while I'm able to implement the subscriptable type, IDEs' code completion feature will be rendered useless** as it will present suggestions for attributes in the `Lazy` class, not `MyClass`.

I've been working with this code:

```
class LazyMetaclass(type):
    def __getitem__(lazy_type, type_annotation):
        return lazy_type(type_annotation)

class Lazy(metaclass=LazyMetaclass):
    def __init__(self, type_annotation):
        self.type_annotation = type_annotation
```

I tried redefining `Lazy.__dict__` as a property to forward to the subscripted type's `__dict__` but this seems to have no effect on the code completion feature of PyCharm.

I strongly believe that what I'm trying to achieve is possible as [typing.Union](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/7d7ffcd51e1ed9bccfa0466b371e490b1555208b/python2/typing.py#L773) works well with IDEs' code completion. I've been trying to decipher what in the source code of [typing.Union](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/7d7ffcd51e1ed9bccfa0466b371e490b1555208b/python2/typing.py#L773) makes it to behave well with code completion features but with no success so far.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For the `Container[Type]` notation to work you would want to create a [user-defined generic type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class Lazy(Generic[T]):
    pass
```

You then use

```
def foo(bla, *, dep: Lazy[MyClass]):
```

and `Lazy` is seen as a container that holds the class.

**Note**: this *still means the IDE sees `dep` as an object of type `Lazy`*. `Lazy` is a container type here, *holding* an object of type `MyClass`. Your IDE won't auto-complete for the `MyClass` type, you can't use it that way.

The notation also doesn't create an instance of the `Lazy` class; it creates an instance of the (private) `typing._GenericAlias` class instead. This instance has an attribute `__args__` to let you introspect the subscription arguments:

```
>>> a = Lazy[str]
>>> type(a)
<class 'typing._GenericAlias'>
>>> a.__args__
(<class 'str'>,)
```

but it's better to use the [`typing.get_args()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args); this function handles a few edge cases with specific type hint objects where accessing `__args__` would lead to suprising results:

```
>>> from typing import get_args
>>> get_args(Lazy[str])
(<class 'str'>,)
```

If all you wanted was to reach into the type annotations *at runtime* but resolve the name lazily, you could just support a string value:

```
def foo(bla, *, dep: 'MyClass'):
```

This is valid type annotation, *and* your decorator could resolve the name at runtime by using the [`typing.get_type_hints()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) (at a deferred time, not at decoration time), or by wrapping strings in your `lazy()` callable at decoration time.

If `lazy()` is meant to flag a type to be treated differently from other type hints, then you are trying to overload the type hint annotations with some other meaning, you want to use the [`Annotated[type_hint, metadata]` annotation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) to attach extra metadata to the type hint for 3rd party use.

E.g. attaching a `Lazy` annotation to the type hint would look like this:

```
from typing import Annotated

def foo(bla, *, dep: Annotated[MyClass, Lazy]):
```

`Annotated[type_hint, ...]` will look like `type_hint` to type checkers.

Use `get_type_hints(..., include_extras=True)` when trying to access such hints from runtime code, otherwise the `Annotated` objects are stripped. Then, when introspecting `Annotated` objects, look at the `__metadata__` attribute to introspect the extra metadata.

Comment: This is much better way of defining custom type annotations. Though it will break code completion features as well.

Comment: @RodrigoMartins: yes, I was in the process of noting this. I don't think you really want to use the `Container[Contained]` notation here, it doesn't apply to your situation.

Comment: First, to just get this out of the way: I don't intent to hack a way to fool the IDE into thinking that `Lazy[A]` is of type `A`. I the same that is observed when using `Union[A, B]`: IDE will code-complete attributes of `A` and `B` because `Union` behaves like a proxy.

The decorator supports string annotations and lazily resolving the name, but it is not intended that annotating your typing with a string will automatically force lazy initialization of the dependency. The lazy initialization feature is meant to be used only when explicitly requested by the caller.

Comment: Second: As you noticed, my `lazy()` function is there only to flag a type to be lazy initialized. But this does not mean to be treated differently by the IDE.

I disagree with "_type hinting simply doesn't support such use cases_", once my decorator has access to the `Lazy[A]` annotation it can apply special behavior based on the existence of a class member, say `Lazy.__lazy_init__`.

I gave the context of lazy init to better justify why I need this. But in the end, regardless of whatever, I want to define a container type `Container[Type]` that will show code completions to `Type`.

Comment: @RodrigoMartins: your *code* can treat `Lazy` differently, but type hinting consumers like your IDE won't. `Union` has specific meaning in the type hinting spec, so it is indeed treated as a proxy by the IDE. It does so because the spec tells it to. There is no provision in the specs to support user-defined proxies however.

Comment: _`Union` has specific meaning in the type hinting spec, so it is indeed treated as a proxy by the IDE. It does so because the spec tells it to. There is no provision in the specs to support user-defined proxies however._

Thanks! This is exactly what I needed to know. For reference, this is confirmed by looking into these commits at PyCharm's repository: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/search?q=Union&type=Commits&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`

Comment: @GeorgeOgden: Python 3.7 (via [PEP560](https://peps.python.org/pep-0560/)) changed what is returned from `GenericType[TypeParameter]` expressions; it is no longer a subclass, so `issubclass(a, Lazy)` indeed no longer works in current Python versions. I've updated my answer and added some notes on Annotations too.