# TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class with Generic type in Python

Tags: python, typing

I'm trying to create a lazy container with typing in python:

```py
T = TypeVar("T")

class Lazy(Generic[T]):
    ...

a = Lazy[str]
issubclass(a, Lazy)
```

However, I'm getting a `TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class` on the last line.
Help to explain this and how I can fix it would be much appreciated.
Code taken from [Custom type hint annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48722835/custom-type-hint-annotation)

Comment: Please put the attribution in the question body itself, thank you.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171189/whats-the-correct-way-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-typing-generic) will help to fix it.

Comment: Hi George, I saw your suggestion edit to my post, but it was actually an answer not an edit, so I rejected it. Please post your answer separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create such a container, you can do:

```py
class Lazy:
    __origin__: Type[T]
    _registered_types: ClassVar[Dict[Type[T], Type[Lazy[T]]]] = {}

    def __class_getitem__(cls, subcls: Type[T]):
        if subcls not in cls._registered_types:
            # save type for type checking
            # List[T] == List[T]
            cls._registered_types[subcls] = type(
                f"Lazy[{subcls.__name__}]",  # add Lazy to start of name
                (cls, subcls),  # inherit from both Lazy and the subclass
                {"__origin__": subcls},  # store the origin attribute
            )
        return cls._registered_types[subcls]
```

This is now a type so supports checking subtypes.

```py
a = Lazy[str]
issubclass(a, Lazy)  # True
issubclass(a, Lazy[str])  # True
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the rationale behind it but it's mentioned in the documentation.

From [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-typing-module):

> Note that special type constructs, such as Any, Union, and type
> variables defined using TypeVar are only supported in the type
> annotation context, and Generic may only be used as a base class. All
> of these (**except for unparameterized generics**) will raise TypeError if
> appear in isinstance or issubclass.

`Lazy` is Generic, When it is subscripted, it becomes a `<class 'typing._GenericAlias'>` which is apparently not accepted as the first parameter of the `issubclass()`.

For `isinstance` or `issubclass`, just use the unparameterized version of your generic classes.

Comment: The rationale behind this decision is clear: `isinstance(something, list[int])` semantically means "`something` is a list of integers", but runtime checks only it's a list. This was prohibited to avoid mistakes caused by such confusion.